# Вместо текста из ресурсов выводятся цифры

Tags: java, android, строки, resources, android-dialog

Не получается вывести текст в окне диалога взятого из ресурсов, вместо него выходят цифры 2131230764. При этом если удалить из кода `getDate()`, то текст выводится правильно.

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// заголовок
adb.setTitle("Заголовок");
// сообщение
adb.setMessage(R.string.text1+getDate()+"text2");
// иконка
adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
// кнопка положительного ответа
adb.setPositiveButton("Да", myClickListener);
// кнопка отрицательного ответа
adb.setNegativeButton("Нет", myClickListener);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.string.text1` – это идентификатор ресурса (в данном случае строки), он имеет тип `int` (то есть это просто целое число).

Класс `AlertDialog.Builder` содержит два метода `setMessage(...)` с различными сигнатурами:

Первый:

```
setMessage(int messageId)
```

Этот метод принимает идентификатор ресурса (текста). То есть, в Вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
adb.setMessage(R.string.text1);
```

Второй:

```
setMessage(CharSequence message)
```

Этот метод принимает объект, реализующий интерфейс `CharSequence`.

В Вашем случае:

```
adb.setMessage(R.string.text1 + getDate() + "text2");
```

используется второй метод и, при этом, происходит неявное преобразование `R.string.text1` из `int` в `String`, откуда и получаем в строке число – это идентификатор ресурса.

Чтобы вывести именно текст, нужно воспользоваться методом, который по идентификатору ресурса возвращает сам ресурс, в данном случае это можно реализовать, например, так:

```
String text1 = YourActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.text1);
adb.setMessage(text1 + getDate() + "text2");
```

Comment: заработало, спасибо!